# Why i am getting error "Type Mismatch"?

Tags: java

I am getting the error type mismatch when i tried to initialize constructor in       main class.

```
public class Test_array 
{
    int arr[];
     Test_array()
      {
          arr=new arr[];     
      }


  public static void main(String[]args)
  {

  }
}

class RecTest 
{
int values[];
RecTest() 
{
values = new int[10];
}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

`arr` is the variable name not the type

```
arr = new int[10];
```

Comment: But in the second class RecTest i didn't get any error  for values =new int[10];  we can initialize variable into constructors.

Comment: That's because you're using the correct syntax using the type when assigning the new array in that case

Comment: can we intialize variable using constructor inside main method ?

Comment: Youre already initializing the array inside the constructor (at least the 2nd one)